# Select buttons in javascript when used in django templates forloop

Tags: javascript, html

I have table in html

```html
<tbody>
    {% for item in cartitems %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td id="counter">
        <button id='minusButton'  class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <i class="fas fa-minus mr-2"></i>
        </button>
        1
        <button id='plusButton' class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <i class="fas fa-plus ml-2"></i>
        </button>
        </td>
        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I want to increment and decrement text in second td which is 1 right now by clicking on plus, minus button

I wrote this javascript but it only works for the first loop of buttons.

```
var plusButton = document.getElementById("plusButton")
var minusButton = document.getElementById("minusButton")

let counter = 1;


plusButton.onclick = function(){
  counter ++
  this.parentElement.childNodes[2].nodeValue = counter
}

minusButton.onclick = function(){
  counter --
  this.parentElement.childNodes[2].nodeValue = counter
}
```

I expect all buttons to select and increment and decrement their respective td text

Answer (score 2):

Good idea Susan let me help you with your problem. The best approach to address this is by creating custom Django Widget. We will edit/create 4 files and then this widget will also be available for rest of your project to be used.

HTML(plusminusnumber.html):

```
<input
    type="number"
    name="{{ widget.name }}"
    class="form-control quantity-number"
    value="{{ widget.value }}"
    min="1"
    max="10"
    {% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %} />
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    data-types="minus"
    data-field="{{ widget.name }}">
    -
</button>
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-plus"
    data-type="plus"
    data-field="{{ widget.name }}">
    +
</button>
```

JavaScript(plusminusnumber.js):

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn-number').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
        type = $(this).attr('data-type');
        var input = $("input[name'"+ fieldName + "']");
        var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
        if (type == 'minus') {
        if (currentVal > input.attr('min')){
        input
            .val(currentVal - 1)
            .change();
        }
        if (parseInt(input.val())== input.attr('min')){
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);

        }
```

CSS(plusminusnumber.css)

```
.quantity-number {
    -moz-appearance:text-field;
}
.quantity-number:: -webkit-inner-spin-button,
.quantity-number:: -webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    margin:0;
}
```

Projectdir/appdir/widgets.py:

```
from django.forms.widgets import Widget

class PlusMinusNumberInput(Widget):
    template_name = 'widgets/plusminusnumber.html'

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('css/plusminusnumber.css',)
        }
        js = ('js/plusminusnumber.js',)
```

Finally we registered all static files with the widget and now you can also use it for rest of your project. For further detail please consult with the official documentation. In case you don't understand any part respond to this solution. Cheers.

UPDATE:

A widget is set of HTML/JS/CSS rules you can define as Jinja template language usage. There are many predefined widgets already created in Django for most common scenarios. You can go ahead and go through official [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/) about Widgets. Please implement the solution in your project so I can help you for any problems you may have.

Comment: I dont know much about widgets can you tell where should i save above files and how do you call this in my working template

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you understand widgets.

Comment: It worked for me like a charm. Thanks @MudassarHashmi for brief explanation. Much appreciated. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I learned about widget because of your ans.

Comment: can you please check `plusminusnumber.js` I am getting a error when I click on + btn saying `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name'quantity']`

Comment: - btn does nothing

Answer (score -1):

id cannot duplicate. `<button id='minusButton'  class="btn btn-default btn-xs">` and `<button id='plusButton' class="btn btn-default btn-xs">`. If for val not 1 then id is duplicate.

Comment: how should I increment id in for loop and how to select that id in javascript then

Comment: you can set `i` value to id and delegate events. For example: plusButton1

Comment: I did not understand, I can set `id = plusbutton{{forloop.counter}}` but how can I select that button in javascript then

Comment: You can find all buttons and set event listener for each or accept `onClick` event for parent of button and check `if(e.target === button_id)` then run your logic